# Proof with Holder's inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, holder-inequality

I am doing exercises about Holder and Minkowsvi inequalities and I have a doubt to an exercise that seems easy, but I am stucked. It uses Holder inequality in functions $\varphi,\psi$.

> **Choosing $\varphi=\psi^{p-1}/||\psi||_p^{p/q}$, show that $\displaystyle{||\psi||_p=\sup_{||\varphi||_{q}=1}\int |\varphi\psi|d\mu}$**.

Here, $1/p+1/q=1$.

Thanks.

Comment: What is that supremum? I don't understand it.

Comment: Please, review the topic. I am sorry for mistake.

Comment: Something is wrong. You are assuming $\psi$ is in $L_p$ and in $L_q$? note that as written, the integral is exactly equal to $\|\psi\|_p$, without taking any supremum.

Comment: @uniquesolution, sorry once again, I revised. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supremum on RHS is over $\phi$ (satisfying $\|\phi\|_q=1$), not over $\psi$.  With this change the proof goes as follows:
RHS $\leq $ LHS is immediate from Holder's in equality. To prove the reverse inequality note that with the special choice of $\phi$ we have  $\int |\phi|^{q}
=\int|\psi|^{(p-1)q} /(\|\psi\|_p^{p})$. From the fact that $\frac 1 p +\frac 1 q=1$ verify that $(p-1)q=p$. It follows now that $\int |\phi|^{q}= \int|\psi|^{p} /(\|\psi\|_p^{p})=1$. Hence RHS $\geq \int |\phi \psi|$. I leave it to you to verify that $\int |\phi \psi|=\|\psi\|_p=$ LHS.

Comment: Many thanks and sorry, but I could not understand yet. Well, once we choice $\varphi$ as fix, I could not understand how can take supremum (because supremum indicates some variating). And I could not finish the problem. Many Thanks.

Comment: Supremum over a set is greater than or equal to any element of the set. So RHS $\geq \int |\phi \psi | d\mu$ for any $\phi$ such that $\|\phi\|_q=1$. I have defined one special $\phi$ for which $\|\phi\|_q=1$. For this $ \int |\phi \psi | d\mu$ happens to be exactly LHS. So RHS $\geq $ LHS.

Comment: Many thanks, I still cannot understand about define one special $\varphi$ for which $||\varphi||_q=1$... sorry for any inconvenient.

Comment: @Na'omi The question itself tells you how to choose special $\phi$. What you have to do is to calculate $\|\phi\|_q$ (which works out to $1$).

Comment: I was not understanding that $\int |\phi \psi | d\mu$ is $||\psi||_p$ for that $\phi$, so nothing was making sense to me. Now I understand. Many thanks and sorry.